# Infer subclass template types in a template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class that derives from a templated class:

```
template <typename A,typename B>
class TemplatedClass {

};

class Hello : public TemplatedClass<int,float>
{

};
```

Now, I want to make a templated class that will infer the types **int,float** from `Hello`.
I thought I could do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
template <template <typename A,typename B> class C>
class Check
{
    void Foo(A,B,C)
    {
        // A is int .. B is float .. C is Hello
    }
};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Check<Hello> a;
}
```

How can i do this ?

Edit:

I want to pass the class **Hello** and have the template infer the types used by its subclass **TemplatedClass** .

So, when I create a class `Check<Hello>` it will get the types int and float

I can't really change the TemplatedClass to include typedefs (it's from an an external .lib)

**Edit:**

I've changed the template to use **Class** , I get this error though:
error C3200: 'Hello' : invalid template argument for template parameter 'C', expected a class template

Comment: Edited my answer, I overlooked/misunderstood some stuff. Though, the error pretty much hints at what is wrong with your thinking: `Hello` is not a template. See my answer for more.

Comment: I know it's not a template :) That's why I'm asking here, just can't get to the base class properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change that `typename` to `class`, `§14.1 [temp.param] p1`:

> type-parameter:
>
> - class *identifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> - class *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* = *type-id*
> - typename *identifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> - typename *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* = *type-id*
> - template <*template-parameter-list* > **class** *identifier<sub>opt</sub>*
> - template <*template-parameter-list* > **class** *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* = *id-expression*

Next, make a partial specialization:

```
template<class T>
class Check;

template< // not 'typename'   vvvvv
  template<typename,typename> class C,
  typename A, typename B
>
struct Check<C<A,B> >{
  // ...
};
```

Though, you still can't pass just `Hello` to the template, because even though `Hello` derives from `TemplatedClass`, type conversion is not allowed for template parameters:

```
Check<Hello> c; // nope, 'Hello' is not a template
```

You could add the following typedef to the `Hello` class:

```
class Hello
  : TemplatedClass<int,float>
{
public:
  typedef TemplatedClass<int,float> base_type;
};
```

And do:

Check c; // OK
But then the `C` parameter in `Check` will be `template TemplatedClass`, not `Hello`. Sadly, there's no way to achieve that directly. One solution is to pass the derived type either as an extra template parameter or just pass the derived type as the only parameter and do the type extraction internally:

```
template<class T>
class CheckInternal;

template<
  template<typename,typename> class C,
  typename A, typename B
>
class CheckInternal<C<A,B> >{
  public:
     typedef A type_A;
     typedef B type_B;
};

template<class T>
class Check{
  typedef typename T::base_type T_base_type;
  typedef typename CheckInternal<T_base_type>::type_A type_A;
  typedef typename CheckInternal<T_base_type>::type_B type_B;

  void foo(type_A a, type_B b){
    // ...
  }
};

// usage:
C<Hello> c; // OK!
```

Comment: `typename` and `class` are identical in C++ when used in templates. There's no point changing one to the other.

Comment: @DeadMG: No, for a template template parameter, it is important.

Comment: You've got 3 template parameters... passing only 1 (T_Base_type)

Comment: @Yochai: Woops, forgot the partial specialization for the second part, thanks.

Comment: @Xeo: Standard reference, please- I'm sure that they're identical all the way.

Comment: @DeadMG : Xeo is right, test it... it won't pass compilation with "typename"

Comment: @DeadMG: §14.1 [temp.param] p1: "*type-parameter:* ... template < *template-parameter-list* > **class** *identifier(op)*".

Comment: @Xeo, it works .. though you got a few errors, mind if I edit your answer for the working solution  ?

Comment: @Yochai: Sure, do. But please comment what exactly was wrong. :)

Comment: @Xeo: "There is no semantic difference between class and typename in a *template-parameter*.", in §14.2 of the FDIS, of which "*type-parameter*" is a part. @Yochai Timme: My compiler will accept it.

Comment: @Xeo: Just did a little fix (I used an older version, before you edited, when I offered to edit) ... @DeadMG: VS2008 doesn't compile if you change "class C" to "typename C" in this example.

Comment: @DeadMG: There is no difference in a *template-parameter*, but the particular case above is not a *template-parameter* (according to the grammar that is shown a couple of lines above, and from which @Xeo extracted the quote in the comment.

Comment: @Xeo: Can yo uexplain why I need to forward declare **CheckInternal** with a single template, and then declare it again with 3 ? I can't understand the logic, and why it doesn't scream "redefinition" ?

Comment: @Yochai: What I did there is called a **partial specialization**. It is kinda like a pattern match. When `CheckInternal` is used with a template that itself takes two parameters, e.g., `Foo<int,float>`, the specialized version is chosen. You can see this with the `class CheckInternal<C<A,B> >`. The part in angle brackets is the partial specialization.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
template <template <typename A,typename B> typename C>
class Check
{
     template<typename A, typename B>
     void Foo(A a, B b) {
        // C<A,B> would reconstruct the template type
     }
}

// use: 
Check<Hello> a;
a.Foo(true,1.f);
```

or alternatively, this (it's not exactly clear what your intent is):

```
template <typename A,typename B>
class TemplatedClass {
   typedef A TypeA;
   typedef B TypeB;
};


template <typename C>
class Check
{

     void Foo(typename C::TypeA& a, typename C::TypeB&) {}
}

// use: 
Check<Hello<int,float> > a;
a.Foo(1,1.f);
```

Comment: I've edited the question so hopefully it's a bit clearer. I can't really change the TemplatedClass to include typedefs (it's from an an external .lib)

Comment: I've managed to get your first suggestion kinda working, it needs to be **class C** instead of **typename**. but it still doesn't work, I've added the error to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
template <typename A,typename B>
class TemplatedClass {
public:    
    typedef A firstType;
    typedef B secondType;
};

class Hello : public TemplatedClass<int,float>
{
public:    
    typedef firstType Type1;
    typedef secondType Type2;
};

template <typename C>
class Check
{
    typedef typename C::Type1 A;
    typedef typename C::Type2 B;

    void Foo(A,B,C)
    {
        // A is int .. B is float .. C is Hello
    }
};
```

Comment: I can't really change the TemplatedClass to include typedefs (it's from an an external .lib), But good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it by creating a templated class for Hello and then typedefing a specialization of it. Something like:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
class HelloBase : public TemplatedClass<A, B>
{
public:    
    typedef A Type1;
    typedef B Type2;
};

typedef HelloBase<int, float> Hello;

template <typename C>
class Check
{
    typedef typename C::Type1 A;
    typedef typename C::Type2 B;

    void Foo(A,B,C)
    {
        // A is int .. B is float .. C is Hello
    }
};

...

Check<Hello> a;
```

So TemplatedClass doesn't need to change, and you can put everything you were going to put in Hello into HelloBase (using the templating as a tool for simply carrying around types).

Answer (score 1):

What you want is impossible in the general case- what if `Hello` derived from `TemplatedClass` twice?

It is, however, fairly simple to do, even non-intrusively, under C++0x.

```
template<typename A, typename B> struct retval {
    typedef A first;
    typedef B second;
};
template<typename one, typename two> one first(const TemplatedClass<one, two>& ref);
template<typename one, typename two> two second(const TemplatedClass<one, two>& ref);
template<typename T> class Check {
    typedef decltype(first(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr))) first;
    typedef decltype(second(*static_cast<T*>(nullptr))) second;
};
```

In C++03 then you can still get the parameters inside the method, but can't access them outside, unless you insert special typedefs.